# Wait for an animation to finish

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know how to use a callback to wait for an animation to finish when I process the animation directly, but if the animation is called from another function, then how can I do it?

For example, I have an element, `#btn`, and an animation is triggered when I click it:

```
$('#btn').click(function() {
   //bla bla...
});
```

Then I call it using `$('#btn').click();` in another function:

```
function foo() {
   $('#btn').click();
   $('#avatar').fadeIn('slow'); //-->I want this animation to run after #btn has finished, but I don't know how to use a callback for this situation...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `promise` and `done` methods:

```
$('#btn').trigger('click').promise().done(function(){
     $('#avatar').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FsyBZ/

Note that it only works when you select the element that currently is getting animated. the best option is using `animate` callback function.

```
$('#elem').animate({}, duration, function(){
   // ...
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this if at time there is only one animetion on page:

```
function foo() {
   $('#btn').click();
   $(":animated").promise().done(function() {
      $('#avatar').fadeIn('slow');
    });
}
```